# ES6 NPM RollUp.Js failing Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, callback, rollup

Using NodeJS for RollUp.js.
When I try to create a callback function, like so, I get "Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function", what am I doing wrong?

main.js

```
import { intro } from './modules/intro.js';
import { CallWhenReady } from './modules/_checker.js';

// Run Application
window.onload = function () {
    CallWhenReady(intro);
};
```

_checker.js

```
export function CallWhenReady(callback)
{
   callback();
}
```

intro.js

```
export function intro()
{
   console.log('Intro has started.');
}
```

Comment: `e`, what is `e`

Comment: rollup minifies js and converts it, e is callback() at _Checker.js

Comment: So  in effect `e` === `intro` here? does "intro" get changed also?  I say this to perhaps learn a bit here myself.

Comment: the rollup bundler simply rewrites things and makes it shorter, better performance etc. 

This is the code generated:
https://hastebin.com/kicayozive.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I actually found the issue!

My passed argument, the function in my belief, was rendered undefined.
This was because I had another file affecting my code that ran the same callback function over and over, not passing the argument again.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so we can close this. Thanks!